# Vscode git shortcut "ctrl+enter to commit on master" not working on Linux mint

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ja1P.png)

None of the given shortcuts for GitHub is not working. I am unable to use the git feature in the Source Control section using Mouse or Keyboard. I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia.

Comment: kernel ?
uname -r

Comment: and check your key bindings,  file-> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts. search for your binding if not define it.

Comment: Except that your key bindings are meant to run some sort of Git commands, this seems to have nothing to do with Git, and everything to do with your editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem has been solved by merging this code

```
"git.suggestSmartCommit": true,
```

in settings.json file

Answer (score 0):

I was overriding the default gitlens command in my keybindings.json, however in the latest version of that plugin the "when" property's value changed, from

```
{
        "key": "alt+a",
        "command": "gitlens.toggleFileBlame",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && gitlens:isTracked"
},
```

to:

```
{
        "key": "alt+a",
        "command": "gitlens.toggleFileBlame",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && gitlens:activeIsBlameable"
},
```